How can I transform or preprocess a general field in zod?
I am new to using zod and am looking at existing code for a project. I want to apply trim and I want its value to remain with the trim, I understand that I can use transform or preprocess. When applying the zodResolver an object like this is passed:
export const candidateFormSchema = object({
candidate: object({
 first_name: validate.textfield("First name", true, 255),
 last_name: validate.textfield("Last name", true, 255),

And textfield has this defined:
    import { string, z, ZodString } from "zod";
import { Field } from "./field";

export class TextField extends Field<ZodString> {

  constructor(fieldName: string) {
    super(fieldName, string());
  }

  public isRequired() {
    this.condition = this.condition.min(1, `${this.fieldName} is required`)
    return this;
  }

  public maxLength(max: number) {
    this.condition = this.condition.max(max,`${this.fieldName} must be less than ${max} characters`)
    return this;
  }

  public minLength(min: number) {
    this.condition = this.condition.min(min, `${this.fieldName} at least ${min} characters`)
    return this;
  }

  public isOptional() {
    return this.condition.optional()
  }

  public isOptionalAndCanBeEmpty() {
    return this.condition.optional().or(z.literal(""));
  }

}

export default function textfield(fieldName: string, required?: boolean, max?: number, min?: number) {
  let condition = string().trim();

  if (required) condition = condition.min(1, `${fieldName} is required`)
  if (max) condition = condition.max(max,`${fieldName} must be less than ${max} characters`)
  if (min) condition = condition.min(min, `${fieldName} at least ${min} characters`)
  
  return required ? condition : condition.optional().or(z.literal(""));
}

I'm not sure where I can apply the trim.

If you want to change the value just for testing you will need something custom like refine or superRefine or maybe a regex, which i will implement here.

const MaxRgx = (max) => new RegExp(`^\\s*\\S.{0,${max}}\\S\\s*$`); //return true when too big
const MinRgx = (min) => new RegExp(`^\\s*\\S.{${min},}\\S\\s*$`); //returns false when too small

As zod provides regex for strings we can then just change the method:
//....
  public maxLength(max: number) {
    this.condition = this.condition.regex(MaxRgx(max),`${this.fieldName} must be less than ${max} characters`)
    return this;
  }

  public minLength(min: number) {
    this.condition = this.condition.regex(MinRgx(min), `${this.fieldName} at least ${min} characters`)
    return this;
  }
//....

See it in this playground

Note: I tried to keep it like your implementation, but i would probably just use superRefine

